# Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, sequelize.col(`col`)); returns no data

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a `mysql` database which contains metadata for a video library. I want to be able to make changes to the video's metadata on my UI and then save a new instance with a more recent version, but want to keep the old version archived in my database. Then when I use `sequelize.findAll` I only want to return the most recent version. Here is my schema for the database

```
CREATE TABLE `ututs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aem_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `locale` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `metadata` json NOT NULL,
  `validated` json NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I use `mySQLworkbench`, I can make this query

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id), aem_id, ANY_VALUE(`locale`), ANY_VALUE(status), MAX(version), ANY_VALUE(metadata), ANY_VALUE(validated), ANY_VALUE(created_on), ANY_VALUE(modified_on) FROM ututs AS Utut WHERE Utut.locale = 'en_US' AND Utut.status IN (1, 2) GROUP BY aem_id;
```

and return the data as expected. However, when I try to make the call using Sequelize:

```
UtutModel.findAll({
      attributes: [
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`id`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`aem_id`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`locale`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`status`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`MAX`, Sequelize.col(`version`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`metadata`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`validated`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`created_on`)),
        Sequelize.fn(`ANY_VALUE`, Sequelize.col(`modified_on`))
      ],
      group: ['aem_id'],
      where: UtutModel.buildWhere(req.query)
```

I get the correct number of entries I expect to return, however, they are missing the data for each column.

```
Utut {
    dataValues: {},
    _previousDataValues: {},
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions: { 
        timestamps: false,
        validate: {},
        freezeTableName: false,
        underscored: true,
        underscoredAll: false,
        paranoid: false,
        rejectOnEmpty: false,
        whereCollection: [Object],
        schema: null,
        schemaDelimiter: '',
        defaultScope: {},
        scopes: [],
        indexes: [],
        name: [Object],
        omitNull: false,
        tableName: 'ututs',
        sequelize: [Object],
        hooks: {},
        uniqueKeys: {} 
   },
   _options: { 
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array] },
   __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
   isNewRecord: false 
},
```

Is there a way to use `GROUP BY` in the sequelize call that will return the data that I'm not using?

Also, if I drop the `ANY_VALUE` fns, I get this error

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'utut.Utut.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the schema of the table and the SQL statement that returns the error.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).